# Why can't I modify my shop page in Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I can not seem to figure out how I can modify the styling of the shop page on my Odoo website.

I've been trying to look it up online but I do not see anyone else mention it and I do not see how I can modify it in the documentation or on the tutorials they offer on their website or Odoo.

Seems like I can modify all the other pages but the shop page.

Does anyone know how to enable the editing feature for the shop page?

Comment: The shop page is rendered basically using QWeb templates. I'm not sure how it's done with the contact page, but on older versions, the contact page was rendered, too. So you probably have to make custom code to change the shop page.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change about the shop page? Although I agree with @CZoellner 's assertion.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit some features for example layout, category position and show/hide buttons of the products page from the editor by selecting the products page and in the right side you can customize it as you can see in the below screenshot.

[image]

If you want to change the style, you need to override the QWeb templates as mentioned by @CZoellner in the comment.